# Node.Js - Socket.io - Angular -> How to receive data/ send data on a priority basis with multiple events?

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

There is a socket connection established between client and server.

Event 1 - 1000+ records for each second you will receive from the socket

Event 2 - To get the statistics report.

After connection establishment server will start sending 1000+ records to UI endlessly, now the user requesting the statistics report parallelly. Now event 2 should be given priority and served first over an Event1. Once done with the statistics report, again should start the formal process.

How to achieve it in Socket.io.?

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 
  socket.on('test', (message) => { // event 2
    io.emit('stats', "STAT");
  });

  socket.on('new-data', (message) => { // event 1
    while(true)    {
    //this will be executed everytime
    io.emit('new-message', message);
    }

  });

 
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code you' re-implementing, please?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed added